# Is it possible to execute a program as another user via cmd or powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I know its possible to run a program as another user, but it still runs in your own environment.

What I want to do is remote powershell into a users machine and then make a program pop up on their screen.

I'm on server A. Computer A has an account logged in, User1.

I want to send a command to that machine to make program.exe pop up on User1's screen.

Is that possible?

Comment: Best way I know is to use task scheduler.

Comment: Ditto to what PetSerAI says, but you can also leverage MS SysInternals PSExec to run stuff in another user context. See the PSExec docs on that topic or the other blogs regarding it. All-that-being-said, no, you cannot do this natively in PowerShell in a explicit or implicit remote command invocation.